# send Session Description from node server to client

Tags: node.js, web-applications, xmlhttprequest, html5-video, webrtc

Do I need to use a websocket to send JSON data to my client? (it's a tiny session description)

Currently my client-side code sends a session description via XHR to my Node.js server. After receipt, my node server needs to send this down to the other client in the 'room'.

I can achieve this using socket.io, but is it possible to do anything a bit faster/ more secure, like XHR for example?

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly understood your question...well for my all WebRTC experiments...I'm using Pubnub (websocket, socket.io etc) .... https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/ ... I found Pubnub is faster and seems good and easy....I do all things in HTML file...no need to worry about server (like node.js !!)....I know node.js is easy...I love it too...but for WebRTC experiments...we should focus on WebRTC JavaScript APIs...to build something better....

Comment: My project aims to have minimal dependancies - for this reason I am not hosting it on appspot, so I don't benefit from the channel API, nor do I wish to rely on pubnub or pusher...

It's good to see your experiments, though. :)

My question is simple: If I have sent a session description (via XHR) to my server from client a, which is the optimal method for sending it to client b?

Comment: For your information, I'm not using Google App Engine Channel APIs...As I said, my experiments are HTML-only!...which can be hosted on any server (even on codepen.io!!)....XHR is better for signalling but there are many chances for failure...also you've to make so many requests!!!....it is true that my experiments are dependent upon PubNub...but this is the only dependency....when you use JQuery...you are dependent upon JQuery!...I use Pubnub for leaving server outside and playing with RTCWeb JS APIs...personally I prefer socket.io over XHR for signalling

Comment: Happy new year, Muaz!

I assumed you were using channel API due to your use of appspot... I think pubnub is a bit like a wrapper for sockets?? I just don't like to be so dependant on a service like pusher or pubnub - I like to understand, and control every aspect of my system.

I think you only need to exchange session descriptions to allow p2p connection... According to this [http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=E8C8ouiXHHk#t=1008s] I will only need each client to send 1 XHR and receive 1 XHR... That seems doable?

Comment: I want my system to be as good or better than the channel API, if at all possible... Being written using Node, it already has an advantage (channel api uses python). I will release my code as an open source system. :)

Comment: I've never tried HTML5 Server Sent Events....these may be helpful to you!

Comment: wow, they do look pretty interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to receive the offer from the other side and nothing else, I would suggest you to try HTML5 Server Sent Events.

But this may bring problems due to different browsers support, so I would use a simple long pooling request. Since you only want to get the SDP offer, the implementation is pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to use the WebSocket API to send JSON data from client to client via a server, but unless you use Google's proprietary App Engine Channel APIs, then the WebSocket API is probably your best choice.

Also, please keep in mind that you're not only sending session descriptions, but also candidate info (multiple times) as well as other arbitrary data that you might need to start/close sessions, etc.

As far as I know, the WebSocket API is the fastest solution (faster than XHR) for signalling because all the overhead involved with multiple HTTP requests is non-existent after the initial handshake.

If you want to code things yourself, I'd start reading the latest [WebSocket draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17) and learning how to code the WebSocket server-side script yourself or else you will pretty much have to rely on a WebSocket library like Socket.IO or a proprietary solution like Google's App Engine Channel APIs.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [303 HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303)?

The first client send the session description to resource X, the server acknowledges the receipt and responds with a 303 status code that points to a newly created resource Y that accumulates other clients session descriptions.

The first client polls resource X until it changes.

The second client send its session description to resource A, the server acknowledges the receipt and updates resource Y. The first client notices the update with the next poll and will now have the second client's session information.